# Tracing where output is coming from in a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, debugging, scripting, output, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to trace where output (to the console) is coming from in a Powershell script? I've got a script which is outputting information to me but I'm not sure which line is making the output. Is it possible to, for example, use Set-PSBreakpoint and tell it to break when info is returned to the console?

Cheers

---

I'm getting hundreds of "False"s returning on their own lines.
Here's the part of the code where the output is coming from:

```
    $ar = Function-which_returns_array_of_objects
    $gr = Function-which_returns_array_of_objects

    Write-Host "To begin with..."
    Write-Host "$($ar.count) assets"
    Write-Host "$($gr.count) goods"

    foreach($asset in $ar){
        if(!(Test-NoNA -string $asset.Serial)){continue}

        #See if the particular serial number exists in Goods Received
        $found = @()
        $gr | Where {$_.SerialNumber -eq $asset.serial} | %{
            $found += $_
            # and then mark the entry as one that has to be deleted from GR
            $_.Delete = "YES"
        }
        if($found.count -eq 1){
            #Serial Number has been found once in GR
            #We want to check its PN...
            if(Test-NoNA -string $found.PartNumber -and $found.PartNumber -ne $asset.Model){
                #add it to the asset if its good and not the same as the model number...
                $asset.PartNumber -eq $found.PartNumber
            }
        }elseif(!$found -or $found.count -eq 0){
            #No entries found in GR
            #Shouldn't be the case but doesn't actually do any damage as we'd be deleting the GR entry anyway
        }elseif($found.count -gt 1){
            #More than one match for the SN - probably means a SN like "N/A" has got through the earlier checks
            Write-Warning "More than one match for SN: '$($asset.serial)'"
        }else{
            #Default catcher
            Write-Warning "Unknown Error for SN: '$($asset.serial)'"
        }
    }
```

Also, heres Test-NoNA:

```
function Test-NoNA($string){
#check that the given string is not blank, N/A, ?, etc. Returns true if string is good
if($string -and $string -ne "" -and $string -ne "N/A" -and $string -ne "NA" -and $string -ne '?' -and $string -isnot [System.DBNull]){return $true}
}
```

Comment: please post the output so we can make a wild guess as to what line of your still-secret code is triggering the stuff. of course, you _could_ try posting some code ... [*grin*] i understand that it may not be possible to post the whole script - but if you can, please do so. perhaps to Gist.GitHub?

Comment: this line `$asset.PartNumber -eq $found.PartNumber` looks like it is part of the problem. your comment makes it seem that you intended the `-eq` to be `=`. [*grin*]

Comment: Ahhh that's it! That explains some other issues with the script as well.

Comment: kool! glad to know you got it fixed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately,

- **`Set-PSBreakpoint -Command` works well with *explicit* cmdlet calls**,

  - E.g., calls to `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` in script `./myscript.ps1` would cause breaking into the debugger with a prior `Set-PSBreakpoint -Command Write-* ./myscript.ps1` call),
- but **does *not* work with *implicit* output**, from statements whose output is neither captured nor redirected (e.g., `'foo'`, `1 + 2`, `Get-Date`).

<sup>In the specific case at hand, statements such as `$asset.PartNumber -eq $found.PartNumber` caused the unwanted output, due to confusing the `-eq` operator (comparison) with the `=` operator (assignment), as diagnosed by [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey). `-eq` produces output (the Boolean result of a comparison), whereas `=` does not.</sup>

**Workarounds**:

- Run **`Set-PSDebug -Trace 1`** before calling your script, which **prints each source-code line before the output it produce**s, if any. `-Trace 2` provides additional details.
- Use the following technique, which **tells you the location and source code of each statement that produces success output**, whether implicitly or explicitly:

  ```
  ./myscript.ps1 | % { Write-Verbose -vb "Output from $(($entry=(Get-PsCallStack)[1]).Location): $($entry.Position.Text)"; $_ }
  ```

  - The script's success output is processed object by object via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (`%`), producing a verbose message reporting the location (script path and line number) as well as the source code of the originating statement (obtained via [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack)), before passing the object at hand (`$_`) through.
- If you want to **examine the script's runtime state on a given line**, say `15`:

  - `Set-PSBreakpoint -Script ./myscript.ps1 -Line 15`
  - Alternatively, in PSv5+, if modifying the script (temporarily) is an option, place a `Wait-Debugger` call in your script at the location where you'd like to break into the debugger.
- Use the debugging capabilities of **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)** to **set breakpoints and/or step through the execution of your script** statement by statement.

  - Alternatively, use **`Set-PSDebug -Step`** for the equivalent operation directly in a PowerShell window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , try this. This should break whereever a write statement is first found.

```
  Set-PSBreakpoint -Script Sample.ps1 -Command "write*"
```

This command sets a breakpoint on every command in the Sample.ps1 script that begins with write, such as Write-Host. For more
Refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @Harihan thanks, but the output isn't coming from a "Write-*" style command - I think it's being returned from a function or operator. I'm after something which captures when output is generated, not when certain commands are called.

Comment: Then you should post some sample code for better clarification.

Comment: I've edited the question to include some sample code