# Powershell 7 how to open the running console/session from inside the script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, console

I have a Powershell script that is **launched from a Desktop Icon in windows**

Is there any instruction that stops the script
and open the running process/session in a interactive console?
(to inspect vars... testing... etc.)

- something like launching a console in debug-mode from inside the script??

PS:
I know I can do this launching from a Powershell console with "."
+
Also I know I can do this with breakpoints in VSCode

my question is just what is stated above...

launching from console...
but the goal is from a icon....

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Tracing where output is coming from in a Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452660/1701026)?

Comment: Hi iRon... ;-)) already googled similar code,,, it works but does not give you "dynamic control" over the debug option... I already have a nice solution... if nobody comes with a better one I'll put it here as answer in a few days!!!